# Make AJAX post call with data

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax

This is in my default.aspx

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "Default.aspx/Myfunction",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {someParameter: "some value"},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            },
            error: function (d) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

And this is in my codebehind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string Myfunction(string someParameter)
    {
        return "hello";
    }
```

It keeps going to the error. I see that if I send the Ajax request with null for data and no parameters on the function I get the data "hello" out. So there is some issue in how I send the data, but it is unclear what

Comment: try `data: JSON.stringify({someParameter: "some value"})` instead

Answer (score 1):

Put your parameters in quotes

```
$.ajax({
            url: "Default.aspx/Myfunction",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'someParameter': 'some value'},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            },
            error: function (d) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Data object must be a single string.

```
data: JSON.stringify({someParameter: "some value"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
data: {someParameter: "some value"},
```

to:

```
data: {"someParameter": "some value"},
```

JSON object properties needs to be enclosed with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do the same thing:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "RouteService.asmx/getRouteData",
    data: { techID: techID, jobID: jobID },
    success: function(msg) {
        processRouteData(msg);
    }
```

Try removing this line:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```